# InnerText and InnerHTML value undefined, even the value exist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I try to change html text value and get the structure with **document.getElementsByClassName("parent-nav")**

This html page using Vue.js.

When I do **document.getElementsByClassName("parent-nav").innerHTML** or **document.getElementsByClassName("parent-nav").innerText** it is return *undefined* even it have values.

What I missed here ?

This is the result of the structure that I got from **document.getElementsByClassName("parent-nav")**

```
HTMLCollection
​
0: a#parentnavi__BV_toggle_.nav-link.dropdown-toggle.parent-nav
​​
__vue__: Object { _uid: 17, _isVue: true, "$options": {…}, … }
​​
_prevClass: "nav-link dropdown-toggle parent-nav"
​​
accessKey: ""
​​
accessKeyLabel: ""
​​
assignedSlot: null
​​
attributes: NamedNodeMap(7) [ id="parentnavi__BV_toggle_", role="button", aria-haspopup="true", … ]
​​
baseURI: "http://localhost:8080/#/photos"
​​
charset: ""
​​
childElementCount: 1
​​
childNodes: NodeList [ span ]
​​
children: HTMLCollection { 0: span, length: 1 }
​​
classList: DOMTokenList(3) [ "nav-link", "dropdown-toggle", "parent-nav" ]
​​
className: "nav-link dropdown-toggle parent-nav"
​​
clientHeight: 40
​​
clientLeft: 0
​​
clientTop: 0
​​
clientWidth: 176
​​
contentEditable: "inherit"
​​
contextMenu: null
​​
coords: ""
​​
dataset: DOMStringMap(0)
​​
dir: ""
​​
download: ""
​​
draggable: true
​​
firstChild: <span>
​​
firstElementChild: <span>
​​
hash: "#parentnavi"
​​
hidden: false
​​
host: "localhost:8080"
​​
hostname: "localhost"
​​
href: "http://localhost:8080/#parentnavi"
​​
hreflang: ""
​​
id: "parentnavi__BV_toggle_"
​​
innerHTML: "<span>Photos</span>"
​​
innerText: "Photos"
​​
isConnected: true
​​
isContentEditable: false
​​
lang: ""
​​
lastChild: <span>
​​
lastElementChild: <span>
​​
localName: "a"
​​
name: ""
​​
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
​​
nextElementSibling: <ul class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="parentnavi__BV_toggle_">
​​
nextSibling: <ul class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="parentnavi__BV_toggle_">
​​
nodeName: "A"
​​
nodeType: 1
​​
nodeValue: null
​​
nonce: ""
​​
offsetHeight: 40
​​
offsetLeft: 4
​​
offsetParent: <li id="parentnavi" class="nav-item b-nav-dropdown …opdown col-sm-2 p-1 m-0">
​​
offsetTop: 4
​​
offsetWidth: 176
​​
onabort: null
​​
onanimationcancel: null
​​
onanimationend: null
​​
onanimationiteration: null
​​
onanimationstart: null
​​
onauxclick: null
​​
onblur: null
​​
oncanplay: null
​​
oncanplaythrough: null
​​
onchange: null
​​
onclick: null
​​
onclose: null
​​
oncontextmenu: null
​​
oncopy: null
​​
oncuechange: null
​​
oncut: null
​​
ondblclick: null
​​
ondrag: null
​​
ondragend: null
​​
ondragenter: null
​​
ondragexit: null
​​
ondragleave: null
​​
ondragover: null
​​
ondragstart: null
​​
ondrop: null
​​
ondurationchange: null
​​
onemptied: null
​​
onended: null
​​
onerror: null
​​
onfocus: null
​​
onformdata: null
​​
onfullscreenchange: null
​​
onfullscreenerror: null
​​
ongotpointercapture: null
​​
oninput: null
​​
oninvalid: null
​​
onkeydown: null
​​
onkeypress: null
​​
onkeyup: null
​​
onload: null
​​
onloadeddata: null
​​
onloadedmetadata: null
​​
onloadend: null
​​
onloadstart: null
​​
onlostpointercapture: null
​​
onmousedown: null
​​
onmouseenter: null
​​
onmouseleave: null
​​
onmousemove: null
​​
onmouseout: null
​​
onmouseover: null
​​
onmouseup: null
​​
onmozfullscreenchange: null
​​
onmozfullscreenerror: null
​​
onpaste: null
​​
onpause: null
​​
onplay: null
​​
onplaying: null
​​
onpointercancel: null
​​
onpointerdown: null
​​
onpointerenter: null
​​
onpointerleave: null
​​
onpointermove: null
​​
onpointerout: null
​​
onpointerover: null
​​
onpointerup: null
​​
onprogress: null
​​
onratechange: null
​​
onreset: null
​​
onresize: null
​​
onscroll: null
​​
onseeked: null
​​
onseeking: null
​​
onselect: null
​​
onselectstart: null
​​
onshow: null
​​
onstalled: null
​​
onsubmit: null
​​
onsuspend: null
​​
ontimeupdate: null
​​
ontoggle: null
​​
ontransitioncancel: null
​​
ontransitionend: null
​​
ontransitionrun: null
​​
ontransitionstart: null
​​
onvolumechange: null
​​
onwaiting: null
​​
onwebkitanimationend: null
​​
onwebkitanimationiteration: null
​​
onwebkitanimationstart: null
​​
onwebkittransitionend: null
​​
onwheel: null
​​
origin: "http://localhost:8080"
​​
outerHTML: "<a id=\"parentnavi__BV_toggle_\" role=\"button\" aria-haspopup=\"true\" aria-expanded=\"false\" href=\"#parentnavi\" target=\"_self\" class=\"nav-link dropdown-toggle parent-nav\"><span>Photos</span></a>"
​​
ownerDocument: HTMLDocument http://localhost:8080/#/photos
​​
parentElement: <li id="parentnavi" class="nav-item b-nav-dropdown …opdown col-sm-2 p-1 m-0">
​​
parentNode: <li id="parentnavi" class="nav-item b-nav-dropdown …opdown col-sm-2 p-1 m-0">
​​
part: DOMTokenList []
​​
password: ""
​​
pathname: "/"
​​
ping: ""
​​
port: "8080"
​​
prefix: null
​​
previousElementSibling: null
​​
previousSibling: null
​​
protocol: "http:"
​​
referrerPolicy: ""
​​
rel: ""
​​
relList: DOMTokenList []
​​
rev: ""
​​
scrollHeight: 40
​​
scrollLeft: 0
​​
scrollLeftMax: 0
​​
scrollTop: 0
​​
scrollTopMax: 0
​​
scrollWidth: 176
​​
search: ""
​​
shadowRoot: null
​​
shape: ""
​​
slot: ""
​​
spellcheck: false
​​
style: CSS2Properties(0)
​​
tabIndex: 0
​​
tagName: "A"
​​
target: "_self"
​​
text: "Photos"
​​
textContent: "Photos"
​​
title: ""
​​
type: ""
​​
username: ""
​​
<prototype>: HTMLAnchorElementPrototype { toString: toString(), target: Getter & Setter, download: Getter & Setter, … }
​
length: 1
​
parentnavi__BV_toggle_: <a id="parentnavi__BV_toggle_" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle parent-nav" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#parentnavi" target="_self">
​
<prototype>: HTMLCollectionPrototype { item: item(), namedItem: namedItem(), length: Getter, … }
AboutNavBar.vue:47
onmozfullscreenchange is deprecated. localhost:8080
onmozfullscreenerror is deprecated. localhost:8080
```

Comment: As you can see from the output, `getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection; `innerHTML` however is a property of a single element.

Comment: @ChrisG how to get the value of innerHTML or the innerText ? 

I have try 

var dataOne = document.getElementsByClassName("parent-nav"); dataOne.getElementsByTagName("span"); 

but the return still undefined

Comment: Assuming the result is stored in `elements`, you can use `elements[0].innerHTML`. However, you're not supposed to manipulate the DOM in a Vue app anyway.

Answer (score 1):

the browser does not know how many element with that class there are, since your using a class there could be multiple. therefore document.getElementsByClass() returns an array of all the elements that contain that class.

so either you could use ID's or you could do something like:

```
document.getElementsByClass("some-class")[0].innerHTML;
```

ofcourse if you dont know the specific index you could just use a variable

Answer (score 0):

`getElementByClassName` returns an `Array of Elements` not the Element so if there is still only element in the Array you have to first access the first Element from Array and then try to user `innerHTML` or something else